# Efficiency of delayed token ring insertion?

Tags: networking, network-efficiency

Let N be the number of stations in the ring, THT the token holding time, Tt be the transmission time of packet, Tp be the propagation time of packet on Channel/ Link.

Then Cycle Time = N * THT + Tp (this is cycle time for token)

and efficiency = (useful time)/(Cycle Time)

Here useful time is stated as N * Tt. (justified as transmission time at each station in single cycle of token passing)

And thus proven efficiency = (N * Tt)/(N*THT + Tp)

Now THT depends on what strategy we are using. If I am using delayed token ring then only one station transmits the data and other station doesn't transmit the data, but [everywhere](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficiency-of-token-ring/) showing in useful time Tt multiplied by N.In this case, THT = Tt + Tp
So, cycle time = Tp + N*(Tt + Tp)

Efficiency, e = (N*Tt)/(Tp + N*(Tt + Tp)).
My question is why we multiplied  Tt by N inspite of one transmits the data?

Comment: Off-topic and obviously (obsolete) homework, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in delayed token ring N=1 since only one station transmitting the data so, Efficiency, e = Tt/Tp + Tt + Tp=Tt/2Tp + Tt .